# Contacts Framework - fetching Email Field in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to fetch needed fields from the contacts, using the Contact Framework. All needed fields are properly fetched, EXCEPT the email.  If there is one contact without an email recorded, then the entire app crashes.  If all contacts have an email defined, all works well.  I have a class called `ContacList` in which a method
`fetchContactsFromContactsFrameWork` is defined as follows:

```
-(void)fetchContactsFromContactsFrameWork{

    contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    NSArray *keyToFetch = @[CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactGivenNameKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactPostalAddressesKey,CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey,CNContactOrganizationNameKey];


    CNContactFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:keyToFetch];

    [contactStore enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil usingBlock:^(CNContact * _Nonnull contact, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        [groupsOfContact addObject:contact];
    }];

    phoneNumberArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
    NSDictionary *peopleDic;
    for (CNContact *contact in groupsOfContact) {
        NSArray *thisOne = [[contact.phoneNumbers valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"digits"];

        peopleDic = @{@"name":contact.givenName,
                      @"familyName":contact.familyName,
                      @"company":contact.organizationName,
                      @"image":contact.thumbnailImageData != nil ? contact.thumbnailImageData:@"",
                      @"email":contact.emailAddresses.firstObject != nil ? contact.emailAddresses.firstObject:@"",
                      @"phone":thisOne,
                      @"selected":@"NO"
                      };

        [phoneNumberArray addObject:peopleDic];
    }

    totalPhoneNumberArray = [phoneNumberArray mutableCopy];
}
```

I am then using the array totalPhoneNumberArray in my PeopleTableViewController where I want to have access to the fetched information. In this I have created a method fetchedContacts, that loos like:

```
 - (void)fetchContacts{
    [[ContactList sharedContacts] fetchAllContacts]; //fetch all contacts by calling single method thanks to class 'ContactList"
    NSArray *contactsArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    _arrayOfContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //This will be the edited array to pass to the next ViewController
    contactsArray = [[ContactList sharedContacts]totalPhoneNumberArray];//fetched original array now has local name 'contactsArray'

    if (contactsArray.count !=0) {

        for (int i=0; i<contactsArray.count; i++) {
            NSMutableArray *person = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//person array will hold 6 properties...

            UIImage *contactPic = [UIImage imageWithData:[[contactsArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"image"]] ?: [UIImage imageNamed:@"noPerson.png"];

            [person addObject:contactPic];
            [person addObject:[[contactsArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]];
            [person addObject:[[contactsArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"familyName"]];
            [person addObject:[[contactsArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"company"]];
            [person addObject:[[contactsArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"phone"]];


            CNLabeledValue *emailValue = [[contactsArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"email"] ?:[[CNLabeledValue alloc]initWithLabel:@"email" value:@""];

            //[person addObject:@"no email"];
            [person addObject:emailValue.value];

            //person array now has the form:{image,name,familyName,company,phone,email}

            [_arrayOfContacts addObject:person];//arrayOfContacts holds all 'persons' fetched from main contactsArray...
        }

    }

}
```

As I explained already, this works perfectly, UNLESS one person has an empty email field, in which case it crashes...I have tried so many things: Turning the `CNLabeledValue` *emailValue to a `NSString`, testing for the length of that string, to no avail.  Any help will be so much appreciated...

Comment: Which line in your code is the crash happening at?

Comment: Code crashes when I try to use emailValue.value (with one person or more not having an email). For instance:

    [person addObject:emailValue.value];

Comment: Hopefully @Rob's answer helps you. If not, I would inspect the value of `emailValue.value` to make sure it is not `nil`; attempting to add a `nil` object will result in problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have code that says:

```
CNLabeledValue *emailValue = [[contactsArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"email"] ?: [[CNLabeledValue alloc]initWithLabel:@"email" value:@""];
[person addObject:emailValue.value];
```

But, when you populated that email value in the dictionary, you said that if there was no email address, use `@""`. So, the code above will then proceed to call `value` on `@""`, which will not work.

Rather than populating the dictionary with `@""` when there is no email address, I'd suggest not setting that dictionary key at all. Or, if you're going to use a "special value" to indicate that there was no email address, you'd generally store `[NSNull null]`. Frankly, you should be doing the same with the image, too.

For example, I might do:

```
peopleDic = @{@"name"       : contact.givenName ?: @"",
              @"familyName" : contact.familyName ?: @"",
              @"company"    : contact.organizationName ?: @"",
              @"image"      : contact.thumbnailImageData ?: [NSNull null],
              @"email"      : contact.emailAddresses.firstObject ?: [NSNull null],
              @"phone"      : thisOne,
              @"selected"   : @"NO"
              };
```

Of course, that means that when you retrieve the `email` value, you check to see if it is `NSNull`, and if so, set the label accordingly:

```
for (NSDictionary *contact in contactsArray) {
    NSMutableArray *person = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//person array will hold 6 properties...

    UIImage *contactPic = [contact[@"image"] isKindOfClass:[NSData class]] ? [UIImage imageWithData:contact[@"image"]] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"noPerson.png"];

    [person addObject:contactPic];
    [person addObject:contact[@"name"]];
    [person addObject:contact[@"familyName"]];
    [person addObject:contact[@"company"]];
    [person addObject:contact[@"phone"]];

    CNLabeledValue *email = contact[@"email"];
    [person addObject:[email isKindOfClass:[CNLabeledValue class]] ? email.value : @""];

    //person array now has the form:{image,name,familyName,company,phone,email}

    [_arrayOfContacts addObject:person];//arrayOfContacts holds all 'persons' fetched from main contactsArray...
}
```

---

If you're interested in showing phone numbers as a string, there are a few options. Here are a few alternatives:

```
for (CNContact *contact in groupsOfContact) {

    // if you want all phone numbers, you can get as an array, or build a joined string

    NSArray *allPhoneNumberAsArray = [[contact.phoneNumbers valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"stringValue"];
    NSString *allPhoneNumberAsSingleString = [allPhoneNumberAsArray count] > 0 ?[allPhoneNumberAsArray componentsJoinedByString:@"; "] : @"No phones";

    // if you want only home phone numbers, filter those with `label` of `CNLabelHome`

    NSArray *allHomePhoneNumberAsArray = [[[contact.phoneNumbers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"label == %@", CNLabelHome]] valueForKey:@"value"] valueForKey:@"stringValue"];
    NSString *allHomePhoneNumberAsSingleString = [allHomePhoneNumberAsArray count] > 0 ? [allHomePhoneNumberAsArray componentsJoinedByString:@"; "] : @"No home phones";

    // if you only want the first home number, it's even easier

    NSString *firstHomePhoneNumberAsSingleString = [allHomePhoneNumberAsArray firstObject] ?: @"No home phones";

    ...
}
```

Comment: Rob, thanks for your response.  I edited the Dictionary key as you suggest to:
@"email":contact.emailAddresses.firstObject != nil ? contact.emailAddresses.firstObject:[NSNull null],

and added this to my ViewController:

    if ([emailValue.value isEqual:nil]) {
                [person addObject:@"No Email"];
            }
            else{
                [person addObject:emailValue.value];
            }

Error I got is:

reason: '-[NSNull value]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Correct, so when you retrieve the email value from the dictionary, you have to test to see if it is `NSNull` or not, only calling `value` if it isn't.

Comment: I understand the idea. Unfortunately it does not work UNLESS all contacts have an email.  So basically, I'm still unable to test for NSNull.  The moment I delete anyone email from the contacts, my app crashes!!  Could you be a bit more specific and provide the code that you have in mind? I know I'm missing some subtle details...

Comment: I already updated my answer that shows how it works. Refresh the page if you don't see the code sample.

Comment: Rob, your sample edited code worked perfectly!! What a nice clean example on how to use the Dictionary values.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Rob, sorry to bother again with one more quick question: To retrieve the phone number(s) may I assume that the phone number also belongs to the CNLabeledValue class?If so, I would think I can do a similar process to the one you used to fetch emails.  I tried that, without success.  I changed the directory entry to:

    @"phone"      : thisOne ?: [NSNull null]

and the call as:

    CNLabeledValue *phone = contact[@"phone"];
            [person addObject:[phone isKindOfClass:[CNLabelHome class]] ? phone.value : @"No Phone"];

All I get on my phone labels is: "No Phone"

Comment: @Miguel - The `phones` property of `CNContact` is not a `CNLabeledValue` object (and certainly isn't a `CNLabelHome`; lol). It is a `NSArray` of `CNLabeledValue` objects. I've updated my answer showing you how you can build arrays or strings of various phone numbers.

Comment: If I can get an array of 'home', 'work', iPhone', and 'mobile' numbers.  Each person will have an array of these 4 numbers, each element being a NSString. Can the array be populated with "No Phone" string entries for cases where there is no phone provided for any of the 4 choices? That way the array will never be empty. I have a knack for running into empty arrays!!
I appreciate very much your guidance...

Comment: See my process for getting the `allHomePhoneNumberAsSingleString`. Then you can repeat that for work, iPhone, mobile, etc. and build an array of them. By the way, your notion of storing things as arrays in a particular order is a bit suspect. This applies not only to the phone numbers, but is a broader issue, including the whole `_arrayOfContacts` which is an array of arrays whose inner array has a "magic" order where you have to magically know that the third item in the array is the company name. It's a very fragile structure. I'd personally stick with my array of `CNContact` objects.

Comment: Your point is well taken.  I see exactly the weakness in my approach.  I will keep this in mind as I learn more about the structure of this new Framework, and how to work with arrays in general.  So, the Dictionary definition does not need to change for the @"phone" : ? I assume I will just call these arrays from my ViewController?

Comment: I'm actually suggesting a radically simpler approach. Why not just stick with your `groupsOfContact` array of `CNContact` and call it a day? Why are your transcribing that array of `CNContact` to an array of dictionaries (`totalPhoneNumberArray`) at all? (There actually are scenarios you might do that, but don't do so unless your need to.) But, there is definitely no benefit to then convert that into an array of arrays. Hey, do whatever you want, but it is a lot of work for no reason. Re `phone` structure, it depends upon what you need and I've shown you a few alternatives above.

Comment: @Rob- I will follow your advise and stick with the much more consistent approach, especially as I better understand how the objects are designed to work. You have helped me tremendously, I truly appreciate your input and wise suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
        NSMutableArray *emailArray;
        NSString* email;
        for (CNLabeledValue <NSString *>*label in contact.emailAddresses)
        {
            email = label.value;
            NSLog(@"email : %@",email);
            if ([email length] > 0) {
                [emailArray addObject:email];
            }
        }
```

Comment: These above code snippets give the email values of home, work,icloud and other